# Visual Studio 2008/2010 on Windows 8 - problems?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, compatibility

I am looking for any information that can be provided regarding problems with the use of Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 on Windows 8 (x64). I have been able find the following [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2735834) that identifies the acknowledged problems for VS2010 on W8, but I cannot find any similar articles for VS2008.

Specifically, I use VS2008 for mobile development so I cannot simply upgrade the projects to 2010/2012 (yet) but I do also have some web application projects and there may even be a couple of console and/or Windows Forms projects kicking around too.

I will be wanting to install Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2012 along side each other.

I know that the obvious answer is to try it, but I need to be confident before I upgrade my production PC and therefore would like to hear of any issues other users may have encountered (any any workarounds that have been determined to go with them where appropriate).

Comment: you install VS on your production PC? VS2008 will install fine. you may have to babysit the installer as it will install .net 3.5

Comment: If you add .NET 3.5 first (Add/Remove Windows Features), it does not try to reinstall it and you do not get this problem. (I found this out installing all 3 on a test W8 device). Thanks though.

Comment: Would it be best to install the versions of Visual Studio, in the order they were released?  VS 2008 first, then VS 2010 and finally Vs 2012?

Comment: That is what I did; VS2008, VS2008SP1, VS2010, VS2012, Windows Updates. As previously mentioned though, ensure that you enable .NET 3.5 via Windows Features before VS2008.

Comment: Darin how about getch() on VS2012? :) Personally I did not use it but young (students) programmers try to learn C++ by _old_ books. So they use POSIX getch() in very first homeworks. Not all of them read message from compiller about using _getch() but not old one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A colleague and I have both now been running VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012 along side each other on Windows 8 for some time now and have yet to discover any problem in doing this.

Therefore, I must submit that there are no problems.

For note, this includes mobile, web & report projects on VS2008, Web & WPF projects on VS2010 and Web, WPF and WinForms projects on VS2012 so I think there is a sufficient spread there to justify my answer.

Comment: So you can carry on with existing VS2008/VS2010 projects in VS2012, but can you create new projects to build for Windows7/XP? I read somewhere that they were forcing you to re-build apps for Windows 8

Comment: I am building apps with VS2008/2010 that target XP through W8. VS2012 will target the same with the exception that you cannot use .NET 4.5 on XP/2003. This may also affect click-once installers, though that may have been fixed with update 1 which allowed C++ targeting for XP (though I have not tried it).

Answer (score 3):

> I will be wanting to install Visual Studio 2008, 2010 and 2012 along side each other.

No, you really no longer need that. Actually with VS2012 you don't need to upgrade the projects when you open them (at last !!!). You could open VS2010 projects without modifying their format. They will still be compatible with older versions. So you really no longer need VS2008 and VS2010.

Personally I am only using VS2012 on Windows 8 x64 and working on VS2012 projects without any issues with it.

Comment: I tried project sharing between 2012 and 2010SP1 during with the final beta and found that each time the project was opened with 2010 after being opened by 2012 the solution and project files were often modified again. I take it this has now been resolved then and once 2012 has modified them 2010 accepts those modifications without wanting to change things back?

Comment: Also, as I stated originally, I still need VS2008 for mobile (WM6.x) development. I have read that it is due to be added to VS2012 in 2013/Q1, but it was once scheduled to be added to VS2010 and that never happened (and I suspect the VS2012 support will be embedded 7 only anyway)

Comment: Is this situation still unchanged, Martin? If you open a VS 2010 project, using VS 2012, make some modifications and check it into source control; and then someone else using VS 2010 opens it do they still find the solution and project files to have changed?

Comment: The compatibility isn't full and you need to check here if it covers your specifics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh266747(v=vs.110)

Comment: Actually, "You really no longer need that" is not correct in all situations. For example, if you need to compile for compact framework, post-2008 products don't do it. It's not advisable to tell people what they need without actually knowing their needs.