# Windows Server 2012 SQL Server 2012 and .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, .net-framework-version

We want to start developing on the newer versions of Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012. At the moment we are using Visual Studio 2010 with the .NET Framework of 4.0. We are not creating desktop apps, we are creating ASP.NET apps.

Before we spend a bunch of money on a new server and new server software, we were wondering if this can be done like this. I am sure someone has tried this out there, and maybe could share their PROs and CONs with this.

I tried to ask this question on superuser and I was told that it belonged here. [Link here](https://superuser.com/questions/634400/windows-server-2012-sql-server-2012-and-net-framework-4-0)

**TLDR**
My specific question is can you develop ASP.NET 4.0 apps with Visual Studio 2010 on Windows Server 2012 using SQL Server database version 2012?

Comment: Don't cross post, either delete your old question first or flag for a moderator to move it here (also as you where told on the other site, this question is primarily opinion based, the SE network is for practical specific problems that can have a definite "right" answer. So your question will likely be closed here too)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I disagree my question is not opinion based. I have a set of tools, can I use them in this environment or not.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain how and where should this question be asked?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain What part of "We want to start developing on the newer versions of Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012." did you not understand? Where did you get Windows 8 from? Perhaps read the question before you comment on it.

Comment: Windows 8 and Server 2012 are the same kernal, similar to 7 and Server 2008 R2 and Vista and Server 2008. I do admit I did say the wrong thing. However you still have not clarified your point what is your question about "...developing on the newer versions of Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012." What do you want us to tell you? Are you asking can you develop applications for server 2012 without owning 2012? Your actual question is still very unclear to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2008/2010 on Windows 8 - problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12543374/visual-studio-2008-2010-on-windows-8-problems) (like I said 2012 and Windows 8 are the same Kernel).

Comment: Nobody will be able to answer this question using stackoverflow. Stackoverflow requires answer to be at least 30 chars. "Yes" is only 3 chars, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that technology stack is compatible you should have no problems using Windows Server 2012 and SQL Server 2012 with Visual Studio 2010